# How to retrieve all instances on the JHipster API for entities

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

When calling the generated api when using a paginator, is there any way i can call the generated REST-api to retrieve ALL instances of an object, insted of only the first 20,30,40 etc?

I find that since i am using pagination for my entity-creation and management, when i want to utilize these entities in other views (self created), then the API does not provide all the instances when calling the `entity.query()` in angular/js.

Is this a limitation to JHipster, or can i call the REST-API in any other way supplying info to discard the paginator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old question but for anyone who's looking for easy solution. You need to override default PageableHandlerMethodArgumnetResolver bean:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolver.setFallbackPageable(Pageable.unpaged());
        argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify existing rest controller for that entity. Here is an example with a `Center` entity.

I return all centers if there is no value for offset and limit.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/centers",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<Center>> getAll(@RequestParam(value = "page" , required = false) Integer offset,
                              @RequestParam(value = "per_page", required = false) Integer limit)
    throws URISyntaxException {
    if(offset == null && limit == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Center>>(centerRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        Page<Center> page = centerRepository.findAll(PaginationUtil.generatePageRequest(offset, limit));
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/centers", offset, limit);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Center>>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Then in angular, you just have to call `Center.query();` without params.

Comment: This works, but i feel like JHipster should have this as default. If i use the entity-manager to re-create my entities, then i would loose these changes :/

Comment: Use a VCS to track changes and eventually revert them if you want to keep what you've done.

Comment: I don't think that Jhipster should have this by default. By selecting pagination when asked by generator, you don't expect users to be able to get all instances in one shot. Imagine you have millions of instances.

Comment: is it posible to do from client side? i mean with angularjs ? 
I am having the same issue , but I am trying to figure it out from client side